# react - child not updating when props updated through parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a react native component -

```
export default class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      behavior: 'padding',
      text: '',
      messages: this.props.chat.messages
    };
  }

  updateText() {
    this.setState({
      messages: this.state.messages.concat( { message: this.state.text } )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={this.state.behavior} style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.chatContainer}>
          <MessageList messages={this.state.messages} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <BorderedTextInput
            placeholder="Type something..."
            onSubmitEditing={ this.updateText.bind(this) }
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
            value={this.state.text}
            style={styles.textInput} />
          <IconBar />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    );
  }
}
```

It has messages array in it's state which is update when a text input is used. This is passed to a MessageList component.

```
export default class MessageList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.messages),
    };
  }

  _renderRow(chat){
    return (
      <FadeInListRow>
        <View style={this._bubbleContainerStyle(chat)}>
          <Text style={this._bubbleStyles(chat)}>{chat.message}</Text>
        </View>
      </FadeInListRow>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.timeContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.timeText}>
            Mon, Jun 2, 22:09
          </Text>
        </View>

        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.listView}
           style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 50}}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I expected the  _renderRow to be called again and my list view to update when the parent state is updated. It is not. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}` to `renderRow={this._renderRow()}`

Comment: @MiGu3X - that's what I initially thought too, but the ListView component expects a function here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow

Comment: Could you try it out at least or it just didn't work?, you can maybe just put renderRow={ () => { this._renderRow() } }

Comment: @MiGu3X: That wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The current code seems fine. I'd suggest two things:

1. Confirm the `message` attribute in `state` is indeed updated `onSubmit()`. You could log it just before the `return` command of the `chat` class.
2. Confirm the `message` attribute in `props` on `MessageList` component gets the update at the same cycles the parent gets updated.

I'm saying this on one premise: Most of the issues with state updates are usually because of inconsistency with data update. If data doesn't change, a component would not be re-rendered.